# Is GETDATE() expensive as DateTime.Now is?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have heard that `DateTime.Now` is very expensive call (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c/1404#1404))

Is `GETDATE()` in SQL 2005/2008 expensive? Have I to cache it into a variable if my stored procedure uses it a number of times?

Comment: Can you share with us where you heard "I have heard that DateTime.Now"?

Comment: Possibly from this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381370/hidden-boxing-in-the-bcl

Comment: It's only expensive if you are calling it a lot.  That question adrianbanks pointed out shows that it takes about 500 ms to call datetime.now 1 million times.  Which is pretty slow, compared to something like incrementing an integer, or concatenating a couple strings (I tested it), but still isn't that slow.  Unless you plan on calling datetime.now a couple million times in some time critical piece of code, it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not expensive: it comes straight from the OS.

I'd cache it anyway. It will most likely be different for separate calls if you have multiple statements. Say you have multiple inserts, surely you'd want the value to correlate acrosss tables?

If it's use in a SELECT, say, for output then it's only evaluated once usually.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask: for the usefuleness or for best speeling mistake today...?

Comment: (don't ever ask these kind of "OR" questions if you can't handle a plain "yes" as the answer) :-)